# Camera Surface View Images Look Stretched

Tags: android, android-camera

In portrait mode, the images look vertically stretched and in landscape mode it looks horizontally stretched.

Although *after capturing the image appears in proper size*.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

You need to choose a preview size that matches your display size. I would suggest changing the preview size setting to match your `SurfaceView` rather than the other way around. While the preview data is just fine, it's not distorted, it will look distorted when flung onto a surface with different aspect ratio.

If you have a full-screen view, then you should find the camera has a preview size matching that size -- at the least there will be one with the same aspect ratio. For example if your screen is 640x480 then a 320x240 preview size will not appear stretched on a full-screen `SurfaceView`.

Comment: To set preview size I am using following code but still surface looks stretched:private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height,
   Camera.Parameters parameters) {
  Camera.Size result = null;

  for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
   if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
    if (result == null) {
     result = size;
    } else {
     int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
     int newArea = size.width * size.height;

     if (newArea > resultArea) {
      result = size;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  return (result);
 }

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? just look for a simple exact match first. Looks like you are copying very old code from Barcode Scanner.

Answer (score 4):

You have to constrain your preview size based on (1) available preview sizes (2) your view. Here is my solution if you still need it:

```
private class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void startPreview() {
        try {
        /**
         * Orientation should be adjusted, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064793/how-to-fix-camera-orientation/26979987#26979987
         */

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            Camera.Size previewSize = null;
            float closestRatio = Float.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetPreviewWidth = isLandscape() ? getWidth() : getHeight();
            int targetPreviewHeight = isLandscape() ? getHeight() : getWidth();
            float targetRatio = targetPreviewWidth / (float) targetPreviewHeight;

            Log.v(TAG, "target size: " + targetPreviewWidth + " / " + targetPreviewHeight + " ratio:" + targetRatio);
            for (Camera.Size candidateSize : previewSizes) {
                float whRatio = candidateSize.width / (float) candidateSize.height;
                if (previewSize == null || Math.abs(targetRatio - whRatio) < Math.abs(targetRatio - closestRatio)) {
                    closestRatio = whRatio;
                    previewSize = candidateSize;
                }
            }

            Log.v(TAG, "preview size: " + previewSize.width + " / " + previewSize.height);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by adding this before calling camera.startPreview():

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); 
parameters.setPreviewSize(yourSurfaceView.getWidth(), yourSurfaceView.getHeight());
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

It might help someone.

Comment: In many cases this throw a Runtime exception (setParameters failed) because surfaceView's size doesn't match any supported preview size.

Comment: You must set the preview size as provided by getSupportedPreviewSize() this is according to the docs. It says you must not set any arbitrary values on setPreviewSize().

Answer (score 0):

just add the following function to set the aspect ratio and preview size

```
private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.getWidth() / size.getHeight();
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.getHeight() - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.getHeight() - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.getHeight() - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.getHeight() - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

use like this

```
 final CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        final CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

        final StreamConfigurationMap map =
                characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);


        // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
        final Size largest =
                Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());

        sensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

        // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
        // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
        // garbage capture data.
       /* previewSize =
                chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        inputSize.getWidth(),
                        inputSize.getHeight());*/

        previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)),textureView.getWidth(),textureView.getHeight());
    } catch (final CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception!" + e);
    } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
        // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
        // device this code runs.
        // TODO(andrewharp): abstract ErrorDialog/RuntimeException handling out into new method and
        // reuse throughout app.
        ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        throw new RuntimeException(getString(R.string.camera_error));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple! If you use surfaceview under actionbar this maybe the problem. I use this line and i can fix, but i not test using action bar.

use this:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are talking about preview, try setting the SurfaceView's size same as Camera's preview size. That way the preview shouldn't be scaled.